# Игнорировать определенные сочетания клавиш в TextInput

Tags: python, kivy

До сих пор не могу найти способ, как можно игнорировать определенные сочетания клавиш в TextInput в Kivy.

Вот простой пример: нужно реализовать зум (изменение размера) текста при нажатии Ctrl Num+/ Ctrl Num-. Это дефолтный шоткат для зума текста в большинстве текстовых редакторов.

Проблема в том, что при нажатии Ctrl Num+, активный TextInput записывает "+" к себе в текст.
Как это можно игнорировать? То есть как не разрешить записывать "+", если нажата кнопка "+" с зажатым Ctrl? И при этом пропускать "+", при простом нажатии "+" (без зажатого Ctrl)

Answer (score 1):

Пока не нашли ничего лучше, как использовать такой подход:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.codeinput import TextInput

KV = """
BoxLayout
    MyTextInput
<MyTextInput>:
    font_size: 24
    text: 'This is my text input'
"""

class MyTextInput(TextInput):

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.readonly = False
        if len(modifiers) and text:

            if modifiers[0] == "ctrl" and ord(text) in [270, 269, 43, 45, 61]:
                self.readonly = True

                if ord(text) in [270, 43]:
                    self.font_size += 1
                    self.cursor = (self.cursor[0] - 1, 0)
                    return
                if ord(text) in [269, 61, 45]:
                    self.font_size -= 1
                    self.cursor = (self.cursor[0] - 1, 0)
                    return

        return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```

Тестировалось пока только на Windows и Linux, серьезных проблем не обнаружено.

обнаружены мелкие моменты:
- например, курсор при зуме прыгает в конец текста (по крайней мере на ubuntu). Похоже на баг TextInput'а Kivy

другие решения давали более серьезные недочеты.
Например, основные проблемы на Linux были такие:
- зум срабатывал (текст увеличивался, либо уменьшался), но вместе с тем не фильтровались клавиши "+"/"-" (добавляясь в текст TextInput'а)
- выделенный текст удалялся при зуме.

В данном решении (по крайней мере на Windows/Linux) таких проблем не обнаружено

Comment: Я ходил вокруг подобного решения, но... Все равно бы не решил. Одной из моиз ошибок было полагать, что modifiers всегда есть) Очень далеко не специалист, но как, я понял, при нажатии нужных сочетаний они не печатаются по причине return, а вот return super(...)... Это что-то вроде использовать стандартную функцию keyboard_on_key_down(...)? А что же делает readonly? Дает разрешение на перезапись класса?

Comment: readonly = True запрещает менять текст text input

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем грамотное решение, но, возможно это будет некоторый трамплин для дальнейшего решения. К сожалению получилось очень громоздко.

Вот:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.base import EventLoop

Builder.load_string('''
<Main>:
    MyOwnTextInput:


''')


class MyOwnTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def chenge_size_method(self,msg):
        #Вот тот метод,который меняет размер шрифта
        #есть нюанс - курсор немного сбивается по координатам(вроде не смертельно сбивается)
        if msg=='numpadadd':
            if self.font_size<50:
                self.font_size+=1
        if msg=='numpadsubstract':
            if self.font_size>10:
                self.font_size-=1

    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        ctrl, cmd = 64, 1024
        key, key_str = keycode
        win = EventLoop.window

        is_shortcut = (modifiers == ['ctrl'])
        is_interesting_key = key in (list(self.interesting_keys.keys()) + [27])

        if not self.write_tab and super(TextInput,
            self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers):
            return True

        if not self._editable:
            if text and not is_interesting_key:
                if is_shortcut and key == ord('c'):
                    self.copy()
            elif key == 27:
                self.focus = False
            return True

        if text and not is_interesting_key:

            self._hide_handles(win)
            self._hide_cut_copy_paste(win)
            win.remove_widget(self._handle_middle)

            first_char = ord(text[0])
            if not modifiers and first_char == 1:
                self._command_mode = True
                self._command = ''
            if not modifiers and first_char == 2:
                self._command_mode = False
                self._command = self._command[1:]

            if self._command_mode:
                self._command += text
                return

            _command = self._command
            if _command and first_char == 2:
                from_undo = True
                _command, data = _command.split(':')
                self._command = ''
                if self._selection:
                    self.delete_selection()
                if _command == 'DEL':
                    count = int(data)
                    if not count:
                        self.delete_selection(from_undo=True)
                    end = self.cursor_index()
                    self._selection_from = max(end - count, 0)
                    self._selection_to = end
                    self._selection = True
                    self.delete_selection(from_undo=True)
                    return
                elif _command == 'INSERT':
                    self.insert_text(data, from_undo)
                elif _command == 'INSERTN':
                    from_undo = False
                    self.insert_text(data, from_undo)
                elif _command == 'SELWORD':
                    self.dispatch('on_double_tap')
                elif _command == 'SEL':
                    if data == '0':
                        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.cancel_selection())
                elif _command == 'CURCOL':
                    self.cursor = int(data), self.cursor_row
                return

            if is_shortcut:
                if key == ord('x'):
                    self._cut(self.selection_text)
                elif key == ord('c'):
                    self.copy()
                elif key == ord('v'):
                    self.paste()
                elif key == ord('a'):
                    self.select_all()
                elif key == ord('z'):
                    self.do_undo()
                elif key == ord('r'):
                    self.do_redo()
                #А вот это я добавил
                elif key==270 or key==269:
                    #Таким образом вызываю свой метод
                    self.chenge_size_method(key_str)
            else:
                is_sdl2 = (EventLoop.window.__class__.__module__ ==
                           'kivy.core.window.window_sdl2')
                if is_sdl2:
                    return
                if self._selection:
                    self.delete_selection()
                self.insert_text(text)
            return

        if is_interesting_key:
            self._hide_cut_copy_paste(win)
            self._hide_handles(win)
        elif key == 9:
            self.insert_text(u'\t')
            return True

        k = self.interesting_keys.get(key)
        if k:
            key = (None, None, k, 1)
            self._key_down(key)


class Main(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__=="__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: на Windows не тестил, на Ubuntu ctrl Num+/Num- дают 2 проблемы (хотя зум происходит): 1) "+" и "-" записываются (добавляюся) в текст TextInput'а при зуме; 2) выделенный текст удаляется. Найдено решение которое работает более-менее стабильно (по крайней мере на Windows/Linux - тестили только на них) - опубликовал как ответ.